# AWK fast value search

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

I need a fast way to match a value in AWK, I have 250k values to search.

I'm doing something like this:

```
    #list with 250k numbers instead of four
    number_list="9998532001 9998536052 9998543213 9998544904"

    if ( index(number_list,substr($5,9)) ) 
         {printf "Value: %s\n",$5;}
```

Any suggestions for a faster search ?

Comment: I donno if there is a speedier loop syntax/trick inside an awk script. But if you can split the array you can alway spawn multiple awks to get he job done.

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you mean by "search" in this context?

Comment: Actually I want to match one ID over a list of IDs ( 250k )...

Comment: and presumably the IDs are the values rather than the keys, right? In that case I don't think there is anything faster than the `for` construct (though you can break out of the look for an average saving of 1/2 the work, of course).

Comment: If you want to do something sophisticated, you should choose another language. Awk is a simple language suitable for simple jobs. If I needed to rewrite a awk script, I'd probably reach for python these days, but perl and ruby both have their supporters.

Comment: I'm not sure you are doing the right thing.. can you post the whole task?

Comment: Now I think the question is more solid, I need to find a match for $5 in number_list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the substring you are searching for is of a consistent length and position in the target string (say the last 6 digits), then you could preprocess the list into an array and you'd be good to go.

Preprocessing step (perhaps in the `BEGIN` target)

```
n=split(numbers_list,a," "); # Rip in input sting into pieces
for ( num in a ) {
    key=substr(a[num],length(a[num])-6,6);  # Get the last six digits

    # Error processing (i.e. collision handling) should go here 

    list[key]=a[num];
}
```

Then when you need to do the lookup

```
i=list[substr($5,9)]   # i is now the full number associated with the key
```

This is only a win if you will do many lookups, because you still have to pay the cost of iterating through that whole list (twice, in fact) during the pre-processing.

---

Note that exact matching to the whole number qualifies as a substring of known length and position, just use `key=a[num]` (which looks funny and leads to several simplifications of the above code, but I'm sure you can figure it out).

---

If you are looking for *any* occurrence of `substring($5,9)` in any of the numbers, this won't work, you'll have to iterate through `n` every time.

Answer (score 0):

Put all the numbers from `number_list` into an awk array and you'll have a fast lookup.

```
if (substr($5,9) in numbers)
```